# Transform XML to XML using XSLT transforming attribute values on target XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have source XML that looks like this -

Currently XML looks as follows:

```
<AllocInstrctn ID="108395820" TransTyp="1" AvgPx="0.35103" AvgParPx="0.35103">
<OrdAlloc ClOrdID="MANUAL" ClOrdID2="2634598" />
<Instrmt Fctr="1000" IssuCtry="ZA" />
```

After transformation I want it to look like this -

```
<AllocInstrctn ID="108395820" TransTyp="1" AvgPx="351.03" AvgParPx="0.35103">
<OrdAlloc ClOrdID="MANUAL" ClOrdID2="2634598" />
<Instrmt Fctr="1" IssuCtry="ZA" />
```

So basically we are multiplying AvgPX attribute in AllocInstrctn tag with Fctr attribute in Instrmt tag and then making the Fctr value as 1. Never used XSLT before. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is AllocInstrctn  the root element? It does not have a closing tag.

Comment: Sorry the structure is <FIXML> <AllocInstrctn> <OrdAlloc /> <Instrmt /> </AllocInstrctn> </FIXML> So FIXML is root, and AllocInstrctn is contained with that, the other two elements are contained within AllocInstrCtn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, learn about the [Identity Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform)

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Using this means you only need to write templates for the nodes/attributes you wish to transform. So, in your case you need a template to transform the `AvgPx` attribute

```
<xsl:template match="AllocInstrctn/@AvgPx">
    <xsl:attribute name="AvgPx">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(number() * number(../Instrmt/@Fctr), '0.00')" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

You also need a (simpler) template to transform the `Fctr` attribute

```
<xsl:template match="Instrmt/@Fctr">
    <xsl:attribute name="AvgPx">
        <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

And that's it! Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="AllocInstrctn/@AvgPx">
        <xsl:attribute name="AvgPx">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(number() * number(../Instrmt/@Fctr), '0.00')" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Instrmt/@Fctr">
        <xsl:attribute name="AvgPx">
            <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this XML...

```
<FIXML> 
<AllocInstrctn ID="108395820" TransTyp="1" AvgPx="0.35103" AvgParPx="0.35103">
<OrdAlloc ClOrdID="MANUAL" ClOrdID2="2634598" />
<Instrmt Fctr="1000" IssuCtry="ZA" />
</AllocInstrctn>
</FIXML>
```

The following is output

```
<FIXML> 
   <AllocInstrctn ID="108395820" TransTyp="1" AvgPx="351.03" AvgParPx="0.35103">
      <OrdAlloc ClOrdID="MANUAL" ClOrdID2="2634598"/>
      <Instrmt AvgPx="1" IssuCtry="ZA"/>
   </AllocInstrctn>
</FIXML>
```

EDIT: If your actual XML has namespaces, try this XSLT instead. Note the namespace declaration at the start, and the use of the prefix (`f:` in this case) to match elements in the namespace.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:f="fixprotocol.org/FIXML-4-4">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="f:AllocInstrctn/@AvgPx">
        <xsl:attribute name="AvgPx">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(number() * number(../f:Instrmt/@Fctr), '0.00')" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="f:Instrmt/@Fctr">
        <xsl:attribute name="AvgPx">
            <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: One quick question. It works with the above code however my FIXML root tag has few attributes as per below. When I add them the out XML is same as input with no transformation (multiplication). <FIXML xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-4-4">

Comment: After the identity template, the next thing you need to learn about is namespaces. "xmlns" is not an attribute. It is a namespace declaration. See http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/04/04/trxml/ for example.

Comment: I've amended my answer to cope with namespaces. If you do spend any time with XML/XSLT then learning about namespaces would be very beneficial. Thanks!